# no module named future_builtins even when future is installed, python2.7.3 on BBB

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am trying to run python django server on Beaglebone Black but getting this error

I have installed future 0.12.1 that was listed in requirements.txt but still the module future_builtins wasn't found. I even tried installing the latest version of future.

python2.7.3 is installed with Django 1.6.5 and Mezzanine 3.1.4

I have tried finding future_builtins.so but didn't find it anywhere, I don't know how to get those for arm arch.

```
root@beaglebone:~/agtoys/agtoys_cms# python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from settings import PROJECT_ROOT, PROJECT_DIRNAME
  File "/home/root/agtoys/agtoys_cms/settings.py", line 429, in <module>
    set_dynamic_settings(globals())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py", line 48, in set_dynamic_settings
    add_to_builtins("mezzanine.template.loader_tags")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1331, in add_to_builtins
    builtins.append(import_library(module))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1267, in import_library
    (taglib_module, e))
django.template.base.InvalidTemplateLibrary: ImportError raised loading mezzanine.template.loader_tags: No module named future_builtins
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, it was easy but I overlooked it

I compiled python2.7.8 myself and inside libs I found future_builtins.so, I just copied the file into the libs of my current python and it worked.

it seems that opkg didn't install the latest version of python and also missed some of the libs, though I compiled python2.7.8 but I couldn't use it as other modules were breaking. 
The proper way of using would have been configuring virtualenv, but then it was again giving a different error, I thought of debugging it sometime later and go with copying that single shared object file and it worked.